# Squirrel SQL Client: How do I get Null to export in csv, currently it is exporting ,, when i want ,null,?

Tags: sql, csv

I am using the Squirrel SQL Client 3.5.0. I am exporting to session/scripts/store results in a sql file.

I need to know when a value is null, as nulls are returned in the results. Please help if you know how I get it to export 'null'. Currently it is just exporting 2 commas as if the field was empty. I must have a setting off, can't find it.

Comment: Can you open the csv in a text editor and replace all ",," with ",NULL," ?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(thidfield,"NULL") from <sometable> WHERE <somestuff>
```

this will put the text "NULL" where the value is null

for SQL-SERVER ... without knowing your server type, the syntax could be different.